# Read the contents from memory in python

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I am trying to read the contents from memory but output is not showing. Kindly let me know where i am doing mistake.

```
import ctypes
memory_address = 0xE000A208 # Get address of sn variable
m = hex(memory_address)
value2 = ctypes.cast(0xE000A208, ctypes.py_object).value #Get value from  address of sn variable
print("value2 =",value2)
```

Comment: Are you getting any type of error ?

Comment: no i didn't get anything on the output screen

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Below is CPython-specific, and you can only read committed virtual addresses in the Python process itself, so depending on what your address represents this may or may not work for you:

```py
>>> import ctypes
>>> test = "Here is a string"
>>> addr = id(test) # In CPython, this is the address of the PyObject in memory.
>>> import sys
>>> size = sys.getsizeof(test)  # this is the size in bytes of the PyObject
>>> s = (ctypes.c_char * size).from_address(addr)  # build byte string
>>> # display all bytes.  These include internal variables as well as string content
>>> s.raw  
b"\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x90\xaeZ:\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc2X'\xb2\x80\x12\x1c\xb1\xe4\x06^:\xf8\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Here is a string\x00"
```